# Creating a mulaw audio file from L16

Tags: audio, gstreamer, pipeline, mu-law

I have a wave file with these properties.

> ```
>    sampling rate = 16000 Hz 
>    encoding = L16 
>    channels = 1 
>    bit resolution = 16
> ```

I want to make 2 pipelines

1) I am throwing this file contents as RTP packets on port=5000

2) listen to port=500 catch the rtp packets and make an audio file with 
following properties

> ```
>    sampling rate = 8000 Hz 
>    encoding = PCMU 
>    channels = 1 
>    bit resolution = 8
> ```

What I have tried is: 
Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/test_l16.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! mulawenc ! rtppcmupay ! udpsink host=192.168.xxx.xxx port=5000
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMU, channels=(int)1" ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! filesink location=/path/to/test_pcmu.ulaw
```

But I am getting L16 file at the Test.ulaw and not PCMU

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect what the `mulawdec` element does:

```
Pad Templates:
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      audio/x-mulaw
                   rate: [ 8000, 192000 ]
               channels: [ 1, 2 ]

  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      audio/x-raw
                 format: S16LE
                 layout: interleaved
                   rate: [ 8000, 192000 ]
               channels: [ 1, 2 ]
```

So basically it decodes Mu Law to PCM. If you want to save the raw Mu Law instead remove the `mulawdec` element.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. It worked by removing the `mulawdec`.